# Changing page position in ASP.NET / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically, after a form is submitted I want the users browser to scroll to an area of the page that is lower down, like you might do with this code:

```
<a href="#lower-stuff">Click here to scroll to stuff lower down in the page</a>
<div id="lower-stuff">Stuff lower down in the page is here</div>
```

Except I'm not sure how to do this.

I'm using gaia (so the page doesn't reload) I tried doing something like this:

```
<gaia:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" Text="Go" CssClass="goButton" **href="#lower-stuff"**/>
```

But that's not allowed apparently . . .

anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve this by calling the javascript page scroll

```
function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
        scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}
```

I agree the above code cant handle dynamic height .

Here you go

```
 $(document).scrollTo('#contact');
```

where #contact is the id of the element you want to scroll to .

For YUI try this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('test');
var myAnim = new YAHOO.util.Scroll(element, {
    scroll: {    
        to: [ 500, test.scrollTop ]
    } 
});
myAnim.animate();
```

here test is the id for the element you want to scroll to.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, however this isn't particularly useful if page content changes so the vertical distance to the object is further from the top :/

Comment: Second code snippet is good, but I'm using YUI not jQuery for this project and I'm having trouble finding the equivalent for YUI . . .

Comment: I would use an anonymous function instead of `'pageScroll()'` for the `setTimeout` parameter, but this should work.

Comment: For YUI3 look at the example given in on this link http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/scroll-nav

Comment: I think that's used for scrolling elements that already have a "href" attribute assigned to them, although I may be wrong. Regardless thanks for all this effort :)

Comment: Actually, I managed to get this working using: 
  <asp:HyperLink runat="server" href="#resultsContainer" ID="SubmitButton" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" Text="Go" CssClass="goButton" /> but I'll give you the accepted answer seeing as no one else got there :)

Comment: gr8 it worked out... and even i got to learn something new. Thanks.